# jQuery changing select value not working when document is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm doing an editing view, and I'm having some trouble trying to assign the value of a hidden input of the form (which contains data from the server) to a select. I try to do it when document is ready, but it just won't do it.

Here's the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {


rige = $('#CargoSeRigePor').val();

$('#CargoDepartamentoId').on('change',function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    var select= $(this);        
    var departamento = select.val();
    var option = select.children('option:selected').val();
    $.post('/sgpag/cargos/listar_cargos/',{id:departamento},function(data){         
                $("#CargoSrp").html(data);
    });
});

$("#CargoDepartamentoId").change();

$("#CargoSrp").val(rige);
```

The last line of code actually does the job when I run it in the console, so...

Thanks.

Comment: And what did you find when you logged `rige` to the console? Did you verify that the `.ready()` callback is even running?

Comment: The value I want the select to have.

Comment: are you sure that #CargoSeRigePor contains the value when you read it? do you load the value via  ajax?

Comment: Are the `select` options dynamically created, or are they present when the page loads? There's no problem with the code in your question. You need to post a full yet minimal example that successfully represents the issue.

Comment: There's a lot of more script working properly inside the same ready()

Comment: The select options are created when the page loads. I'm guessing it has something to do with that.

Comment: Ok I'll add some more code.

Comment: They need to exist before `.val()` will work.

Comment: I think that .post() loads them before the value assignment.

Comment: AJAX requests are asynchronous. The `$.post` data returns long after the `.val()` gets invoked. That's why there's a callback. Its so that any code that needs the response will not run until that response arrives. If it could be executed in order like that, there wouldn't be any need for the callback. Put the `.val()` code inside the callback, and you're set.,

Comment: Oh... Ok I think I get you.

Comment: Solved it! Thank you cookie monster!

Comment: @cookiemonster Please summarize your assistance into an `answer` to allow OscarB92 to accept your solution. Doing so will also make it easier for future readers to find the solution to their own problem.